# AWS API Gateway not passing Endpoint request header even after transformation

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to pass an Authorization header through API Gateway into a Lambda function.  I can see the key in the gateway logs.  But, even after I transform the input with the standard script (see below), the Authorization head still doesn't make it to the Lambda function.

Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

API Log excerpt

```
Endpoint request headers: 
{
 X-Amz-Date=20220419T143450Z,
 x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=?????????,
 Accept=application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
 User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_hhompg4,
 Host=lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com,
 X-Amz-Content-Sha256=??????????????????????????????????????????????????,
 X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-????????-???????????????????,
 x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=abcd-4e32-1234-???????????????, Authorization=*********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************70cc,
 X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:-----------------:asfd/test/POST/,
 X-Amz-Security-Token=---------------------------------------// [TRUNCATED]
```

Method Execution / - POST - Integration Request Transformation script:

```
{
    "method": "$context.httpMethod",
    "body" : $input.json('$'),
    "headers": {
        #foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())
        "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))"
        #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
        #end
    }
}
```

event keys arriving to lambda function:

```
2022-04-19T14:29:34.457Z    INFO    Object.keys(event) [
  'resource',
  'path',
  'httpMethod',
  'headers',
  'multiValueHeaders',
  'queryStringParameters',
  'multiValueQueryStringParameters',
  'pathParameters',
  'stageVariables',
  'requestContext',
  'body',
  'isBase64Encoded'
]
```

Object.keys(event.headers)

```
[
  'accept',
  'accept-encoding',
  'accept-language',
  'cache-control',
  'content-type',
  'Host',
  'origin',
  'referer',
  'sec-ch-ua',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform',
  'sec-fetch-dest',
  'sec-fetch-mode',
  'sec-fetch-site',
  'sec-fetch-user',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests',
  'User-Agent',
  'X-Amzn-Trace-Id',
  'X-Forwarded-For',
  'X-Forwarded-Port',
  'X-Forwarded-Proto'
]
```

Comment: The content type is: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" not "application/json".  Cool, the script is now being run.  But for headers, I'm still not getting the Authorization header into Lambda.

Comment: ```
INFO Object.keys(event) [ 'method', 'body', 'headers' ]
```

```
INFO Object.keys(event.headers) [
  'accept',
  'accept-encoding',
  'accept-language',
  'cache-control',
  'content-type',
  'Host',
  'origin',
  'referer',
  'sec-ch-ua',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform',
  'sec-fetch-dest',
  'sec-fetch-mode',
  'sec-fetch-site',
  'sec-fetch-user',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests',
  'User-Agent',
  'X-Amzn-Trace-Id',
  'X-Forwarded-For',
  'X-Forwarded-Port',
  'X-Forwarded-Proto'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to see my request header (Authorization) in request headers but the same was not visible in the endpoint request headers. Found that you have to enable the 'Use HTTP Proxy integration' option while setting up the integration point.
[image]

Comment: The option will be `Use Lambda Proxy integration`, if the integration type is `Lambda function`